# How to replace a string according to their length with "*" (astrik) letter

Tags: javascript, regex

From the back-end json data, i am receiving a "password" infromation. But I requested to hide the password information in the html page.

I know there is a way to hide using the input type "password". But in this html just i am showing the details hiding the password.

I am trying to replace the string using the regexp method. but not working.

here is my try:

```
var st = "Shchool"; //it is 7 letters, i need to print 7 '*'

st.replace(/./g, "*"); // i am trying to replace.

console.log(st);
```

Comment: If you don't need the password going through, just don't add it to the `JSON string` response. Why send it and try to mask it later? Then someone debugs your page, stick a breakpoint in the code and just skips this bit. Done, they have your password.

Comment: This is rather dangerous. Anyone can simply manipulate the JavaScript on your page and disable this method of "hiding" the password.

Comment: add `st=` to `st = st.replace(/./g, "*");` - http://jsfiddle.net/sskezp11/

Comment: A better option would be to pre-hide this data on the server before returning it to the user.

Comment: Basically this is internal application. and all this is by customer requirement

Comment: `st = st.replace(/./g, "*");` should work for you in that case

Comment: Is it necessary that password be passed to the front-end? If not, don't pass it to the front end and don't even expose an API for it. If user wants to remember password, they already have the browser taking care of that for them. Passing the password to the client side is simply exposing the password to the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `String.replace()` return a **new string** with the replacing text, and it doesn't modify the string where you apply the method.

```
var st = "Shchool";
st.replace(/./g, "*"); // returns new string "*******"
```

You need to assign the result to the variable, if you want to change it:

```
st = st.replace(/./g, "*"); // assign the replaced string back to st
```

Now you can log the string:

```
console.log(st);
```

---

[MDN - String.replace() returns a new string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

**Consider masking password with `*` in back-end, replacing it in front-end isn't a good idea!**

---

#### Test code

```js
var st = "Shchool"; // It has 7 letters, I need to print 7 '*'

st.replace(/./g, "*"); // The variable st is NOT modified

console.log("LOG1:",st);

st = st.replace(/./g, "*"); // Assign the return value to st

console.log("LOG2",st);

// Look at the console
```